# bespoke sentiment analysis: scoring documents based on words and their respective scores - R NLP

Tags: r, nlp, tidyverse, tidyr, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to score documents based on the words that occur in them. I have two types of scores for each word occuring in the corpus. It is essentially like a sentiment analysis but with a bespoke dictionary and respective scores. THANK YOU <3

```
#documents to be scored on 2 dimensions: score1 and score2
documents <- data.frame(textID = 1:3, text = c("Hello everybody, pleased to see everyone together", " DHL postmen have faced difficulties this year", "divorcees have trouble finding jobs in this country"), scored1 = rep(NA,3), scored2=rep(NA,3) )

#first scoring dimension
scores1 <- as.matrix(data.frame(words = c("hello", "everybody", "pleased", "to" ,"see", "everyone","together", "DHL", "postmen", "have", "faced","difficulties","this", "year", "divorcees", "trouble", "finding", "jobs", "in", "country" ), scores = 1:20))

#second scoring dimension
scores2 <- as.matrix(data.frame(words = c("hello", "everybody", "pleased", "to" ,"see", "everyone","together", "DHL", "postmen", "have", "faced","difficulties","this", "year", "divorcees", "trouble", "finding", "jobs", "in", "country" ), scores = 10:29))

#the result should look like this, where each text receives a score that represents the sum of #individual word scores: 

#textID                                                  text      scored1 scored2
#1      1   Hello everybody, pleased to see everyone together       28        91
#2      2       DHL postmen have faced difficulties this year       77        140
#3      3 divorcees have trouble finding jobs in this country       128       200
```

Comment: Don't. Words alone are absolutely useless for sentiment analysis.

Comment: It's not words alone. The scores i am using are actually mean word embeddings. I simplified the question.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by

1. `tidytext::unnest_token` the documents into single words
2. `dplyr::left_join` the word scores
3. `dplyr::summarise` to compute the scores for each document

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

#documents to be scored on 2 dimensions: score1 and score2
documents <- data.frame(textID = 1:3, text = c("Hello everybody, pleased to see everyone together", " DHL postmen have faced difficulties this year", "divorcees have trouble finding jobs in this country"), scored1 = rep(NA,3), scored2=rep(NA,3) )

# 1. Get rid of as.matrix

#first scoring dimension
scores1 <- data.frame(words = c("hello", "everybody", "pleased", "to" ,"see", "everyone","together", "DHL", "postmen", "have", "faced","difficulties","this", "year", "divorcees", "trouble", "finding", "jobs", "in", "country" ), scores = 1:20)

#second scoring dimension
scores2 <- data.frame(words = c("hello", "everybody", "pleased", "to" ,"see", "everyone","together", "DHL", "postmen", "have", "faced","difficulties","this", "year", "divorcees", "trouble", "finding", "jobs", "in", "country" ), scores = 10:29)       

# 2. Make words lowercase
scores1 <- mutate(scores1, words = tolower(words))
scores2 <- mutate(scores2, words = tolower(words))

# 3. Compute scores
documents %>% 
  select(-scored1, -scored2) %>% 
  tidytext::unnest_tokens(text, output = words, drop = FALSE) %>% 
  left_join(scores1, by = c("words" = "words")) %>% 
  left_join(scores2, by = c("words" = "words"), suffix = c("1", "2")) %>% 
  group_by(textID, text) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("scores"), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  rename(scored1 = scores1, scored2 = scores2) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'textID' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   textID text                                                  scored1 scored2
#>    <int> <chr>                                                   <int>   <int>
#> 1      1 "Hello everybody, pleased to see everyone together"        28      91
#> 2      2 " DHL postmen have faced difficulties this year"           77     140
#> 3      3 "divorcees have trouble finding jobs in this country"     128     200
```

Comment: thanks @stefan! I get the following error: "Must rename columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `data.frame<
  scores: double
  words : character" even though I checked str(scores1) and str(scores2) and the variables are of type numeric and character. It does not make sense. Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: Hi Scarlett. Hard to tell without the data and code. However, from the error message it's evident that the issue arises is in the last code line `rename ...`. And "`has the wrong type `data.frame`" suggests that there is no column `scores1` after the join and summarise which means, that R thinks that `scores1` refers to the dataframe `scores1`. Not sure what's the issue. But I would suggest to simply drop the last line.